# Visualizing point clouds in WPF Viewport3D is extremely slow

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, point-clouds, viewport3d

I am trying to visualize a point cloud of ~170000 points using WPF's Viewport3D control. After generating the 3D point coordinates I create a triangle with a certain size at each point and add it to a Model3DGroup object which I append to my Viewport aftwerwards.

My problem is that the code below responsible for this takes 3 seconds alone to run. After the Model3DGroup has been added to the Viewport the UI is frozen for another 3-5 seconds more.

How can I make this work faster? Also if Viewport3D can't handle models of this number can anyone recommend an alternative way of visualizing a point cloud in a WPF control?

```
        viewport.Children.Clear();

        Model3DGroup triangles = new Model3DGroup();
        foreach (Point3D point in workspace.PointCloud)
        {
            double x = point.X;
            double y = point.Y;
            double z = point.Z;

            Point3D p1 = new Point3D(x + 0.005, y, z);
            Point3D p2 = new Point3D(x, y + 0.005, z);

            MeshGeometry3D mymesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
            mymesh.Positions.Add(point);
            mymesh.Positions.Add(p1);
            mymesh.Positions.Add(p2);
            mymesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
            mymesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
            mymesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);

            Vector3D Normal = GeometryHelper.CalculateTraingleNormal(p0, p1, p2);
            mymesh.Normals.Add(Normal);
            mymesh.Normals.Add(Normal);
            mymesh.Normals.Add(Normal);

            Material Material = new DiffuseMaterial(
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) { Opacity = 0.5 });
            GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(
                mymesh, Material);

            triangles.Children.Add(model);
        }

        ModelVisual3D modelVisual = new ModelVisual3D();
        modelVisual.Content = triangles;
        viewport.Children.Add(modelVisual);
```

Comment: Even after your optimization efforts, I don't believe you will see the results you are searching for.  You may be better served with a pure native solution and D3D.  Looks like a fun project.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Per [This Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb613553(v=VS.100).aspx):

> Create different models only when they require different Materials or
>   Transforms. Otherwise, try to coalesce many GeometryModel3D instances
>   with the same Materials and Transforms into a few larger
>   GeometryModel3D and MeshGeometry3D instances.

Instead of creating multiple `MeshGeometry3D` create just one and add it to a single `GeometryModel3D`.  Add that single `GeometeryModel3D` to your `ModelVisual3D`.  This should significantly improve the performance of your model (I've experienced this myself).

For additional speed improvements you may be able to create your positions in parallel ([Parallel.ForEach Example](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwilqu7hrt7HAhXFlIgKHZy7CUg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd460720(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGB0Ecy60gA930FP7yb38LOhhJHbw&sig2=T-wUFfWKpHL3C1LUd_ZWYg&bvm=bv.102022582,d.cGU))

```
      List<Point3D> points = new List<Point3D>();
      Parallel.ForEach(workspace.PointCloud, point =>
      {
        //Do Work
      }
      );
      Point3DCollection p3d = new Point3DCollection(points);
      mymesh.Positions = p3d;
```

I haven't tested this code.  There may be some additional work required to get it to work in parallel.  Be sure to create the points in triplets, otherwise you'll get points in a very weird order which will create some crazy triangles.

You can skip the specifying of `TriangleIndices` as they are inferred if not specified.  Although I doubt that will buy you much processing time and I'm unsure if it has performance impacts later.

Comment: hmm...I didn't notice until after I posted this that the question is 2 months old!  Oh, well...For posterity!